# Is there a broader definition of the convolution operation?

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform, convolution, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

The convolution operator is defined as

$${\displaystyle (f*g)(t)\triangleq \ \int _{-\infty }^{\infty }f(\tau )g(t-\tau )\,d\tau .}
$$

where it shares a relationship with the Laplace transform such that:

$${\mathcal{L}\left\{ {f * g} \right\} = F\left( s \right)G\left( s \right)\hspace{0.25in}\hspace{0.25in}{\mathcal{L}^{\, - 1}}\left\{ {F\left( s \right)G\left( s \right)} \right\} = \left( {f * g} \right)\left( t \right) }$$

However, there are many more types of integral transforms than just the laplace transform. For example, the Mellin transform:

$${\displaystyle \left\{{\mathcal {M}}f\right\}(s)=\varphi (s)=\int _{0}^{\infty }x^{s-1}f(x)\,dx.}$$

which has an 'equivalent' convolutional operator of:
$${\displaystyle (f*g)(x)= \ \int _{0 }^{\infty }f(y)g\left( \frac{x}{y} \right) \frac{dy}{y}\,}
$$

Keeping these two examples in mind, is there a a more general convolution operation that has the property:

$$\left( {f * g} \right)\left( x \right) = {\mathcal{T}^{\, - 1}}\left\{ {
\mathcal{T}\left\{ {f} \right\}\mathcal{T}\left\{ {g} \right\}
} \right\}$$

where the transform T is an integral transform of the form:

$${\displaystyle (Tf)(u)=\int \limits _{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}f(t)\,K(t,u)\,dt}$$

Thanks!

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform
https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2017/12/03/transforms-and-convolutions/

Comment: It really depends on what you want it to mean. The last expression you wrote is certainly one way to do it but it can get very tricky.. That requires you know domains and ranges play nicely with your integral operator (or you can drop down to a sufficiently nice subspace to make sense of it). Furthermore, just because you can do that doesn't mean the resulting operation is actually meaningful.